# Differents results for the same query in sql and hql

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I have an application made with angular and java and I try to get datas from a database. So, I try to get my datas in hql (hibernate) but I don't have the same results in hql and in sql for the same query.

This is my sql query :

```
SELECT
  co.label,
  sol.material_code,
  sum(sol.quantity),
  sol.level
FROM sales_order so
  JOIN sales_order_line sol ON so.root_so_id = sol.root_so_id
  JOIN customer cu ON cu.id = so.id_customer
  JOIN country co on co.id = cu.id_country
WHERE so.level = 1
AND sol.material_code in ('AR1MA010', 'VJCNS102088')
GROUP BY co.label, so.level;
```

And this is my hql query :

```
select 
  co.label, 
  sol.materialCode, 
  sum(sol.quantity), 
  sol.level
from SalesOrder so 
  join so.salesOrderLines sol on so.rootSoId = sol.rootSoId 
  join so.customer cu 
  join cu.country co 
where so.level = 1 
and sol.materialCode IN ('AR1MA010', 'VJCNS102088')
group by co.label, sol.level
```

I try to run these queries in console. So, there is no problem with my code but I get 2 results differents.

For the sql query, I have :

```
Argentina   AR1MA010    16000   2
Brazil      VJCNS102088 20      1
Romania     VJCNS102088 12      2
```

and for the hql query I have :

```
Brazil  VJCNS102088 20  1
Romania VJCNS102088 1   1
```

Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: What's the sql that's printed in the console when you run your HQL query? compare that with your plain sql and you can find out the difference.

Comment: You will need to add the Entity classes. Also enable Hibernate logging to see the raw SQL generated by Hibernate.

Comment: How can I do that in intelliJ ?

Comment: join so.salesOrderLines sol on so.rootSoId = sol.rootSoId  looks wrong to me. Shouldn't this not work without the ON clause?

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from  `join so.salesOrderLines sol on so.rootSoId = sol.rootSoId` .

With `so.salesOrderLines`, you make a join with a condition and with the "on" you add a second condition. But in sql, you just have the second condition with the "on". So in hql, there are 2 conditions for the join whereas there is just one in sql.

Comment: So what's the solution?